# What do the off-diagonal elements of Hamiltonian matrix physically represent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory, quantum-states

A briefly question: what's the "physical meaning" of the off-diagonal elements of Hamiltonian matrix? Such as an Hamiltonian Matraix looks like:
$$\hat H = \begin{pmatrix} E_{11} & E_{12} \\ E_{21} & E_{22} \end{pmatrix}$$
My teacher told me such a matrix element :
$$E_{21}=\langle2|\hat H|1\rangle$$
Corresponding to the transition amplitude from $\left| 1 \right\rangle $ to $ 
\left| 2 \right\rangle$. I thought about it for days, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: If diagonal entries exist, $|1 \rangle$ and $| 2 \rangle$ are not eigenstates so we have to worry about one transitioning to the other. Have you seen the fact that $\exp(-i \hat{H} t / \hbar)$ solves the Schroedinger equation?

Comment: @ConnorBehan Yes! You are right! But I have another trouble: I do know this: $E_{21}=\langle2|exp(−i\hat Ht/\hbar)|1\rangle$ represent the transition transition amplitude from $\left| 1 \right\rangle $ to $ 
\left| 2 \right\rangle$ , But I still have no idea about what's the relation between $\langle2|exp(−i\hat Ht/\hbar)|1\rangle$ and $\langle2|\hat H|1\rangle$, may I have more tips from you please?

Comment: @ConnorBehan I tried use Taylor expansion to expand the evolution operator, but it looks can't help since $\left| 1 \right\rangle $ isn't the eigenstate of $\hat H$ as you said, so there is no such $\langle2|(\hat H)^n|1\rangle$=$\langle2|\hat H|1\rangle^n$, I think I still can't say something about it :(

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [Off-diagonal elements of Hamiltonian matrix $H_{12}$ & $H_{21}$: energy of transition from $|1\rangle$ to $|2\rangle$ or amplitude of transition?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/209350/off-diagonal-elements-of-hamiltonian-matrix-h-12-h-21-energy-of-trans)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remember, the meaning of the Hamiltonian in the first place is that it generates time translations via the Schrodinger equation:
$$
i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} |\psi(t) \rangle = \hat{H} | \psi(t) \rangle
$$
You can formally solve the Schrodinger equation of a time independent Hamiltonian as $| \psi(t) \rangle = e^{-i H t / \hbar} | \psi(0) \rangle$. To gain some intuition, expand the exponential in power series:
$$
|\psi(t) \rangle = | \psi(0) \rangle - \frac{i t}{\hbar} H | \psi(0) \rangle - \frac{t^2}{2\hbar^2} H^2 | \psi(0) \rangle + \ldots
$$
Now, imagine starting off your system in state $|1\rangle$. Then, according to the above equation, if $H$ has off-diagonal elements connecting the state $|1\rangle$ to the state $|2\rangle$, then the Schrodinger equation will generate some amplitude for the system at a later time to be in state $|2\rangle$. The rate at which the state transitions from $|1\rangle$ to $|2\rangle$ will be proportional to $\langle 2 | H | 1 \rangle$, at least to first order in $t$. You can see this by simply using a resolution of the identity, $1 = |1\rangle \langle 1| + |2\rangle \langle 2 |$:
$$
|\psi(t) \rangle = |1\rangle -\frac{it}{\hbar} \left( \langle 1 | H | 1\rangle |1\rangle + \langle 2 | H | 1 \rangle |2 \rangle \right) + \ldots
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I still got one last thing to confirm: since $\hat H$ isn't a diagonal matrix (which means $\left| 1 \right\rangle $ and $\left| 2 \right\rangle $ isn't the eigenstates of $\hat H$ ), this lead to: there is no such $\langle2|(\hat H)^n|1\rangle$=$[\langle2|\hat H|1\rangle]^n$ in Taylor expansion, so we do use some kind of approximation in order to better understanding, then we finally get this: $$\langle2|\hat H|1\rangle\propto \langle2|exp(-i\hat Ht/\hbar)|1\rangle$$ Am I right?

Comment: The approximation of stopping at $n = 1$ yes. $\left < 2 | H | 1 \right >$ isn't literally the transition amplitude... just its first non-trivial term.

Comment: @Connor Behan Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

This is similar to Zack's answer, but on a more elementary level.

You need to begin with the [time-dependent Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Time-dependent_equation)
$$i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}|\psi(t)\rangle=\hat{H}|\psi(t)\rangle$$

Using your given Hamiltonian matrix and writing the state
$|\psi(t)\rangle$ as a column vector this becomes
$$\begin{align}
i\hbar \dot{\psi}_1(t)=E_{11} \psi_1(t) + E_{12} \psi_2(t) \\
i\hbar \dot{\psi}_2(t)=E_{21} \psi_1(t) + E_{22} \psi_2(t)
\end{align}.$$

Now let's assume the system starts in state $|1\rangle$.
That means the starting condition is $|\psi(0)\rangle=|1\rangle$
or
$$\begin{align}
\psi_1(0) &= 1 \\
\psi_2(0) &= 0.
\end{align}$$

Then the solution for small $t$ is
$$\begin{align}
\psi_1(t) &= 1 &-i\frac{E_{11}t}{\hbar} &+ O(t^2) \\
\psi_2(t) &=   &-i\frac{E_{21}t}{\hbar} &+ O(t^2)
\end{align}$$

Here you see, it is the matrix element $E_{21}$ determining
how fast the $\psi_2$ component grows from zero to bigger values.

Answer (score 3):

The off-diagonal elements represent the "coupling" between those basis states. I believe it is equal to the transition amplitude within the perturbative approximation.  To understand the off-diagonal elements, consider what would happen if they were zero.  Then the diagonal Hamiltonian matrix is already expressed in the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.  $\hat{H} |1\rangle = E_{11} |1\rangle$ and $\hat{H}|2\rangle = E_{22} |2\rangle$.  This only occurs when $\langle 1|\hat{H}|2\rangle=0$.  If $\langle 1|\hat{H}|2\rangle\ne 0$, then the states $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ are coupled together by that $\hat{H}$, and the eigenstates of $\hat{H}$ will be some superposition of $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$.